# Webview in qr code scanner

Tags: android, webview

```
class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
     @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               return false;

        }
    }

PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

            Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
            barcode.setData(data);

            int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

            if (result != 0) {
                previewing = false;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();

                SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                for (Symbol sym : syms) {

                  String value = new String(sym.getData());
                  if(value.startsWith("http://192.168.1.6")){

                  scanText.setText("QR Code result: " + value);
                    barcodeScanned = true;
                    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient()); 
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(value);

                  }
                  else{
                      scanText.setText("QR Code result 2: " + value);
                      barcodeScanned = true;
                      }
                   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanText);
                    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


                }

            }


        }
    };
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at net.sourceforge.zbar.android.CameraTest.CameraTestActivity$2.onPreviewFrame(CameraTestActivity.java:201)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:864)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-25 20:05:22.714: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have a QR code scanner app. My app stops when the qr code scanned starts with `http://192.168.1.6`. I want to show this link in a webview not in a browser. But if the url does not start with the `http://192.168.1.6` it will open the link in another browser.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace if the app is crashing. Otherwise, tell us what's not working.

Comment: the webview is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function correctly.

First, please do not call `loadUrl` from it. The URL load is in progress already, and calling it again is incorrect.

Second, you can check the URL that is being loaded (it's passed as a parameter to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` for `http://192.168.1.6` and then change the logic to do the right thing depending on whether it's there or not. It sounds like if it's there you just want to `return false` to handle the load in the WebView. Otherwise, you should create and send an ACTION_VIEW Intent to load the URL in the device's Browser and return true.

Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: should i place the webview in a separate xml file or in the main xml file?

Comment: It should be fine to have the WebView in your main XML file. It looks like you are having two problems now that you have pasted the stack trace. What's not working? Are you seeing the crash or it not overriding url loads to 192.168.1.6,or both?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stacktrace, you have a `NullPointerException` on line 201 of CameraTestActivity:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at net.sourceforge.zbar.android.CameraTest.CameraTestActivity$2.onPreviewFrame(CameraTestActivity.java:201)
```

If you want to post the code that contains this line, I can help you track it down.